# How to add Visual Studio code to path variable?

Tags: environment-variables, path

My path variable had corrupted which I have fixed now. But during the process, I lost some of the original entries in the path variable. I specifically want to add entries for visual studio code and Github's atom editor. When I look into their properties, these programs are started using following commands

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\atom\update.exe --processStart atom.exe
```

and

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Code\update.exe --processStart Code.exe
```

What is `update.exe` and how do I add this to `path`?

Comment: You don't add apps to paths, but folders, so the command name and args aren't included. you would just execute `update.exe --processStart atom.exe` in a shell. There are a couple issues though. first, its not really good to create global path var entries that point into a users home directory. other users won't have access to it, but the system will attempt to parse the directory. Second, Update.exe is a very common executable name, and its in both your paths, so the first path  containing an update.exe (when read left to right) will execute every time its invoked.

Comment: As for terminology, update.exe is the application. it was written to accept special options at the command line. `--processStart` tells update.exe to turn on the proccessStart option (which could do anything, but the name implies it will start atom.exe as a child process, so it can be exited when the update is installed). `atom.exe` is an argument to the processStart option. arguments before any options apply to the application, whereas any arguments specified after the first option are arguments to the option they follow. you cannot store this info in the path. try a shortcut instead.